# PHP: WooCommerce webhook fired multible times over the next hour - why?

Tags: php, woocommerce, webhooks

In WooCommerce I have set it up to firing a webhook for the action "woocommerce_payment_complete" but it is firing more than 20 times over the next hour. After this point it stops. The next paid order does the same.

Why is it doing this? I only need to fire once.

I can see in the log of WooCommerce that is showing all the fired webhooks but there so no reason (that I can see) why it re-trying multible times.

Here is something from the log:

```
user-agent: WooCommerce/3.0.4 Hookshot (WordPress/4.7.4)
content-type: application/json
x-wc-webhook-source: https://www.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxx/
x-wc-webhook-topic: action.woocommerce_payment_complete
x-wc-webhook-resource: action
x-wc-webhook-event: woocommerce_payment_complete
x-wc-webhook-signature: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x-wc-webhook-id: 4919
x-wc-webhook-delivery-id: 1117
```

The called page is returning a status 200 and some text. The WC log is saying: Status: HTTP 200 OK

I am using latest version of WC.

I also tried fired it at https://hookbin.com/bin/KG75yPyd where it shows that was fired over 20 times in a short time.